# cannot format the date

Tags: php, date

I need to store the date in the database in the form of day-month-year ("`29-04-2014`"). I have used the following code and inserted in the database. But it is saved in the form of "`Apr 29 2014 12:00:00:000AM`".

```
$date = date("m.d.y");
```

Comment: what is the data type for date in the DB ?

Comment: If you store a date, you should store it in date format. Formatting it is another thing...

Comment: please provide what database you are using and the data type of that field

Comment: USE `$date = data("m-d-Y", time());`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty datetime is the datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: Is there any errors ? Any message ? Did you look at your log files ?

Please make a more constructive comment..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obtain the `$unix_timestamp` of a readable string date you can use `strtotime`:

```
$string_date = '2012-04-03';
$unix_timestamp = strtotime($string_date);

$date = date('d-m-Y', $unix_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an exemple I used it in my code :

```
<?php
    $today =
    $date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime('last Sunday', strtotime(date("Y/m/d"))));
    $date1 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date)+86400);
    $date2 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date1)+86400);
    $date3 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date2)+86400);
    $date4 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date3)+86400);
    $date5 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date4)+86400);
    $date6 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date5)+86400);
    $date7 = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date6)+86400);
?>
```